# What is the simplest way to create a pie chart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, charts

I'm new to charts, graph, so on, and I'm trying to learn them.
I want achieve this pie chart UI, but not sure which approach is the best.
I want to make this piechart as easy to adapt as possible - meaning re-use it in a a diff places on my entire site.

[image]

After doing some researches, I came across some of them, and I've tried

- [`Highchart`](http://jsfiddle.net/bheng/taz17c7t/)
- [`Google Chart`](https://jsfiddle.net/bheng/jacsL55v/)

I've also heard that [d3](http://d3js.org/) library is also a really good to make something like this too. Unfortunately, I'm not looking for anything complicated at this point.

My main goal to make this as simple as possible, as long as it'll re-usable with diff data/color.

---

What is the **simplest** way to create a pie chart ?

Any suggestions /  comment ?

Comment: Google Chart the simplest way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was in your situation, I've tried different scripts about charts and my choice was Google Charts in his version of Material Design:

- Nice Docs.
- Nice Design.
- AJAX.
- Etc.

And it has a lot of charts, not only a Pie Chart.

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in a jQuery solution, there's an easy to use [jQuery wrapper](http://www.zingchart.com/docs/reference/jquery-charts/) for the [ZingChart library](http://www.zingchart.com) that you might be interested in.

Here is [an example of a simple pie chart](http://demos.zingchart.com/view/UFHI9164), all ready to go. Feel free to tinker in that demo and apply styling as you like.

If you have any questions, please reach out. I'm on the ZingChart team.